# which datetime.TryParseExact function will support for format like '2021-11-21 11:34:45.234567+0000' in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to know which datetime.TryParseExact function will support for format like

```
2021-11-21 11:34:45.234567+0000
```

in C#.Net? I am getting above datetime format in my source file.

I have tried `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffffzzz"`, But *doesn't work*. Thanks.

Comment: `yyyy-M-d H:m:s.FFFFFFzzz`? To be on the *safe side*: we have no clue if month, day, hour etc. have *leading zeroes* (that's why I put `M` instead of `MM` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the timezone specifier: K

Try "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffffzzzK"

Comment: Thanks, But Its not working too.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

[image: Example]

```
    string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff zzz";
    var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```

Comment: Thanks, But Its not working